# reactQuery receiving data from api

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, react-query

i'm using reactQuery and i have the problem in getting data from the back (a REST API)

the problem is the page loads before receiving data from the api
so that i have to click in the console of the browser then i click in the page to receive data properly

to resolve that i used to implement the useForceUpdate component like so

```js
export const useForceUpdate = () => {
    const [, forceUpdate] = useReducer(i => i + 1, 0);
    return forceUpdate;
};
```

and in some pages it resolves the problem and some times it's no good

an example to of useQuery functions in my code

```js
export default function useFetchDelivery(idLivraison: number) {
    return useQuery(["deliveries", idLivraison], async () => await fetchDelivery(idLivraison), {
        enabled: !!idLivraison,
        cacheTime: 0,
        onError: (error: AppException) => errorToaster(error.msg),
    });
}
```

Comment: `useFetchDelivery` should rerender the component automatically when the data loads. No need to force update

Comment: hello @KonradLinkowski
thanks for your answer, i understand but i do not know how to do that

Comment: How do you use this `useFetchDelivery`?

Comment: i use useParams of react-router, get the id of the delivery, then call the useFetchDelivery by

Comment: const { deliveryId }: any = useParams();
const { data: delivery }: any = useFetchDelivery(parseInt(deliveryId));
and then i get the delivery object

Comment: So your query should rerender the component. If it doesn't happen  that means that something is wrong.